# how to integrate Secret Manager with elastic Beanstalk

Tags: php, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-secrets-manager

I want to configure Secret Manager with Elastic Beanstalk and for that, i am setting secret manager parameters in elastic beanstalk properties like this

'''$(aws secretsmanager get-secret-value --secret-id arn:aws:secretsmanager:ca-central-1:465688179233:secret:CNP-staging-Secret-credentials-tiQrEv --region ca-central-1 | jq --raw-output '.SecretString' | jq -r .DB_USERNAME)'''

after updating the environment variable, elastic beanstalk work perfect but when I deployed code using AWSCodepipeline, the whole environment(EB) degraded with the following error

'''
SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user '$(aws secrets manager get-secret-value --secret-i'@'192.168.136.223' (using password: YES) (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = ebdb and table_name = migrations and table_type = 'BASE TABLE')
'''
would you let me know how I should integrate the secret manager with Elastic beanstalk

Answer (score 1):

You have to add [secret manager permissions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/secretsmanager/latest/userguide/auth-and-access_examples.html) to IAM role associated with your [Elastic Beanstalk instance profile](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/concepts-roles-instance.html).

Comment: i have added the following policies under aws-elastic beanstalk-service-role
"AWSElasticBeanstalkEnhancedHealth", 
"SecretsManagerReadWrite",
"AWSElasticBeanstalkManagedUpdatesCustomerRolePolicy"
what else i need to add ,please do guide me ,one more thing can this procedure work?